# Loop in R continually runs unexpectedly

Tags: r

I am trying to run a loop that contains a *while* and an *if* statement. The code works outside of the loop but not inside! This is a very *simplified version* which basically is trying to collect sets xx[j] which contain 10 numbers each.

When I run it, it never actually allocates the 'x' to the set xx[j] but I'm not sure why!

```
n <- 10
xx <- list()

for (j in 1:5) {
  xx[j] <= NULL
  while (length(xx[j]) < n) {
    x <- runif(1)
    if (0.5 <= x) {
      xx[j] <- c(xx[j], x) 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For `xx[j]<=NULL`, did you mean to use the assignment operator `<-` or the lesser-or-equal operator `<=`?

Comment: Also, elements of a list are accessed with double brackets `xx[[j]]`.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed and polished the code.

The changes are:

- Elements of a list are accessed with double brackets `xx[[j]]`
- The list is created of the target length `5`
- Removed setting the elements of the list to `NULL` as they are `NULL` initially

The fixed code:

```
n = 10
xx = vector('list',5)

for (j in seq_along(xx)) {
    while(length(xx[[j]]) < n){
        x = runif(1)
        if (0.5 <= x) {
            xx[[j]] = c(xx[[j]], x) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason the code won't work when the "(j in )" is defined rather than using seq_long(xx)? When it's define without the target length I get the following error: Error in xx[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: I used `seq_along(xx)` just to avoid hard coding the vector length multiple times. Once `xx` is initialized, the code works regardless of the length of `xx`. The initial code assumed it to be 5.